# Tests against an api which uses LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have to write some tests against an api which uses internally `LocalDateTime.now()`, does some stuff with this value and returns a pretty long String (~1MB).

I want to write some regression tests to make sure results are the same even if a new release of the api comes out.

Sadly the test results differ every time because `LocalDateTime.now()` always returns different values (surprise, surprise...)

Is it possible somehow to fix the result of `LocalDateTime.now()` to a hard coded value.

Since it only has to work in some unit tests dirty solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Sure.  If you subtract the result of the API from a call to LocalDateTime.now in your test, the result ought to be consistent.

Comment: Thats not possible. The api doesn't simply return the LocalDateTime but does a lot of stuff to create new data which creating is depending on the now()-value. I would have to reimplement everything on test site.

Comment: Then you're going to have to edit your question and explain in much, much more detail the input and the output of the API.

Comment: Do you use `java.time.LocalDateTime` or `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`?

Comment: java.time.LocalDateTime

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: mock static method using Powermock**

You can do this by mocking the static method and returning the correct object each time it is called.

```
 @PrepareForTest(LocalDateTime.class) //This is added added at test class
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class);
 Mockito.when(LocalDateTime.now()).thenReturn(firstLocalDateTime);
 Mockito.when(LocalDateTime.now()).thenReturn(secondLocalDateTime);
```

See https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method

**Option 2**
Wrap the calls in a method that you can mock without using powermock.

Comment: You'd have to use `PowerMockito` since `LocalDateTime` is a final class.